# Read text file into AS3 and see their lines in multiple frames

Tags: actionscript-3, text-files

I would like to see a line of a text file on the frame that I want (and view it in a dynamic text)

this is my text file:

```
Foo
Candy
Bar
Dog
```

This is my code in the first frame:

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
firstLine.wordWrap=true;
firstLine.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var Lines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
    var firstItem:String = Lines[0];
    firstLine.text = firstItem;
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("myfile.txt"));
```

With this I can see "Foo" in the first frame. How could I see "Candy"? a second frame. Is it repeated all this code again?

Is there any way to just invoke the Lines array: Array = e.target.data.split (/ \ n /) and obtain the desired Item?

I hope your advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var currentItem = lines[currentFrame=1];//note that only Class names should be capitalized
textFieldObject.text = currentItem;
```

Run on enterFrame event. Make sure lines is an instance-level variable.

HTH;

Amy

Comment: Do I have to create a class for that?

Comment: I would. If you know how to create a variable that's visible throughout the entire life of a clip you could probably make it work with frame scripts, but since I always aim for scalable, reusable code, I know as little as I can get away with about them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, AS3 is very difficult for me :(